# How to fix a hddplot package installation error

Tags: r, function

Has anyone seen this error message for the hddplot package?

```
install.packages ("hddplot")
library(animation)
library(hddplot)
```

**I was able to successfully install both packages but when I run `library(hddplot)` function I get this error message **

```
> library(hddplot)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘hddplot’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘multtest’
>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that you also need to install the package ‘[multtest](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/multtest.html)’, which is on Bioconductor.

So, to install it, do

```
if (! requireNamespace('BiocManager', quietly = TRUE)) {
    install.packages('BiocManager')
}

BiocManager::install('multtest')
```

Comment: This worked! I appreciate it. Curious to know why does R require me to install it this way?

Comment: @IRTFM No, the issue is that `install.packages` doesn’t automatically install Bioconductor dependencies unless you’ve manually configured your repositories this way, or [if the package description contains the undocumented stanza `biocViews:`](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/3375/29). ‘hddplot’ does *not* include this declaration, and R therefore fails to install its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.